# High Poly on Low Poly Baking in Substance Painter

Tags: texture-baking, artifacts

When I bake high poly on low poly I get some issues (artifacts) on my low poly model. Usually those are straight lines from triangulated low poly which cause these issues. I know that this problem can be tackled by making smoothing grups but Blender has more options than one and I am curious which works best as I have not seen any differences.

1. using autosmooth
2. mark sharp option + autosmooth
3. Using the edge split modifier - This one gives more vertices as it splits them

All have same results and in all cases I get sharped edges around the sharped angles even tho I baked the high poly. Is this normal? 
I have provided an example below of how the artifacts look like.

Plus I would like to here if you have any other option to this problem.

[image]

Comment: Looks like bad topology with almost degenerate triangles.

Comment: Is this a question about Blender?

Comment: Try the remesh modifier with a high resolution.